# Why is .load() not firing?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute this jquery code:

```
$('#imgUnrelatedToCanvas').load(function(){
  $("#loading").fadeOut(1000);

});
```

It is not working. I assume because the canvas on the page shows an ongoing animation - not sure though. It is meant to fire when an image, unrelated to the canvas loads. I can make the same load syntax work on other pages that don't have animation; keen to solve if possible because `.ready()` fires too early. HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="loading">
<img id="spinner"src="gif.gif"/>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img id="imgUnrelatedToCanvas" src="example.svg">  
</body>
```

1. Could someone confirm whether or not it is the canvas animation that is causing my plight?
2. Is there a way to make `.load()` work or do I have to settle for `.ready()`?

Comment: Why not when document ready use fade out u just need to hide loading img right?

Comment: @devpro, I assume because the image might not be loaded in yet

Comment: If it just a loading image display in default when document ready means canvas ready to hide image

Comment: i deleted the canvas. Not that. Yeah .ready fires before the image loads. Im trying to show a loading spinner rather than a large image slowly revealing itself.

Comment: suppose i could change the timer of fade to be more appropriate but that could differ between computers/internet speeds. Also just in principle would like to understand why .load isnt working

Comment: I am talking like that $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loading").fadeOut(1000); or hide(1000);

});

Comment: @pete did u resolved?

Comment: The above .ready() suggestion is a big improvement. Does the job; It shows and hides the spinner. Not perfect though, there is a time between the spinner hiding and image showing where loading is being done. On other pages i have though, .load seems to work a lot more seamlessly. Also, whilst .ready provides a solution, im still a little confused as to why .load wont work.

Comment: Are you binding the load handler within a document.ready callback or is your script located below your DOM, otherwise the image element may not be available when your code is executed.

Comment: @LJ what do you mean by binding? the below? The following doesn't fire. No idea why.   
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#imgUnrelatedToCanvas').load(function(){$("#loading").fadeOut(2000);});
 });